# Fuelphp - Using pagination for displaying pages

Tags: pagination, fuelphp

I'm working on a project with Fuel. I created a pagination , first page has data truly in it but when I click on other pages , url changes but page never refresh and it doesn't show other pages. 
codes:

code in Controller :

```
           $config = array(
'pagination_url' => 'http://localhost/body-app/public/app/list/',
'total_items'    => 12,
'per_page'       => 3,
'uri_segment'    => 5,
// or if you prefer pagination by query string
//'uri_segment'    => 'page',
);
       $pagination = Pagination::forge('mypagination', $config);

       $data['example_data'] = DB::select('*')
                        ->from('bodies')
                        ->limit($pagination->per_page)
                        ->offset($pagination->offset)
                        ->execute()
                        ->as_array();
    $data['pagination'] = $pagination;
              $view=View::forge('app/list',$data);
```

and my foreach in View is something like this :

```
      <?php foreach($example_data as $per) { 

      echo $per['name'] ;
      } ?>
```

and finally code to show pagination :

```
<?php echo Pagination::instance('mypagination')->render(); ?>
```

Comment: This suggests your uri_segment is wrong, so the page number is either not inserted in the URI, or not picked up from the URI (so it always loads page 1).

Answer (score 0):

If you work with segment number, you should change the route.php file, and add the example `'prod/page/(:page)?' => 'prod'` , or add in the you controller one segment string example `'uri_segment'    => 'examplenumberpage'`.